# using jquery mobile radiobutton with mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get the jquery mobile with mvc to create a radio button group.

This is what I have

```
  <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
            <legend>Gender:</legend>
        @*   <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-c" value="on" checked="checked" />
            <label for="radio-choice-c">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-d" value="off" />
            <label for="radio-choice-d">Female</label>
         *@
             @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Consumer.IsMale,"Male")
             @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Consumer.IsMale, "True",new {value="on",@checked = "checked"})
             @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Consumer.IsMale,"Female")
             @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Consumer.IsMale, "False", new {value="off"})
            </fieldset>
    </li>
```

That looks like

[image]

Its not clickable and as you can see there is a radio button within the "Male" button.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I was binding my radiobutton list wrong. This is the correct way if anyone else has the same problem

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Consumer.IsMale, true,new {value="on",@checked = "checked",id="Consumer_IsMale_true"})
<label for="Consumer_IsMale_true">Male</label>

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Consumer.IsMale, false, new {value="off",id="Consumer_IsMale_false"})
<label for="Consumer_IsMale_false">Female</label>
```